# LINQ Query List within a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following list of EF Objects, `Leagues`, where each one has a list of `Teams`. Each `Team` has a Year associated with it

In a WPF form, I have a `combobox` for years to select. When I select a year, I want to be able to sort by Leagues that existed in that year, followed by the teams it had, so that I can populate a `TreeView` for it.

The most I've come to so far is:

```
    public int SelectedYear
    {
        get => _SelectedYear;
        set
        {
            _SelectedYear = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedYear");
            Refresh();
        }
    }

    public void Refresh(object sender = null, EventArgs e = null)
    {
        Leagues = new ObservableCollection<League>(_Locator.Statistix.Leagues.Where(x => x.Teams.Count(t => t.Year == SelectedYear) > 0).ToList());
        foreach(League l in Leagues)
        {
            l.Teams.Where(x => x.Year == SelectedYear);
        }
    }
```

The `League` Object is as follows:

```
public partial class League
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public League()
    {
        this.Teams = new HashSet<Team>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string LahmanID { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}
```

For good measure, here is the `Team` Object as well:

```
public partial class Team
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Team()
    {
        this.Games = new HashSet<Game>();
        this.Games1 = new HashSet<Game>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FranchiseID { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CityID { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BallparkID { get; set; }
    public int LeagueID { get; set; }

    public virtual City City { get; set; }
    public virtual Franchise Franchise { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Game> Games1 { get; set; }
    public virtual League League { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way I can filter Leagues followed by the teams within the same `Leagues` `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Can you show us the League object please?

Comment: @YairHalberstadt I just updated my question, providing the `League` and `Team` objects

Answer (score 0):

if the size of Leagues is not too big, I'd look into gathering data, and then pulling out the ones that you don't need.

```
public void Refresh(object sender = null, EventArgs e = null)
    {
        Leagues = new ObservableCollection<League>(_Locator.Statistix.Leagues.ToList());
        foreach(League l in Leagues)
        {
            l.Teams.RemoveAll(x => x.Year == SelectedYear);
        }
        Leagues.RemoveAll(x => x.Teams.Count == 0);
    }
```

The other alternative is building specialized classes which inherent from ObserableCollection and implements IObseravable in order to build the specialized logic to use the classes as a datacontext for the WPF form which would allow for the system to automatically filter when a different year is selected.

Answer (score 0):

To flatten out many lists as a single list you can use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
// all teams from all leagues
var allTeams = GetAllLeagues().SelectMany(l => l.Teams);

// all teams of the SelectedYear
var teamsByYear = allTeams.Where(t => t.Year == SelectedYear);
```

Comment: That would work, except I want to keep it hierarchical for a TreeView

Comment: I see where you're going, not sure what the best approach is but I found this thread, I hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150036/how-to-data-bind-a-hierarchical-data-to-a-wpf-treeview

Comment: Are you using the Football Data API? I've got a repo on that, although I'm not using WPF, maybe it can be helpful to you! https://github.com/navelDirt/FootballApi

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Refresh(object sender = null, EventArgs e = null)
{
    Leagues = _Locator.Statistix.Leagues.Select(x => new League
        {
             Id = x.Id,
             Name = x.Name,
             Initials = x.Initials,
             LahmanId = x.LahmanId,
             Teams = x.Teams.Where(x => x.Year == SelectedYear).ToList()
        }).Where(x=> x.Teams.Count > 0).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This one might work, although because it's an EF object, I'm getting a `LINQ to Entities` error. Thanks!